# unable to install android 4.3 x86 on virtualbox

Tags: android, virtualbox

i am unable to install android x86 4.3 on host win7 in vbox here is the screen before it reboots and start the same process again

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable Virtualization (VT-x) through system BIOS. After that you should be able to install and boot android x86 in the virtualbox

Answer (score 0):

I dont really have any experience with installing Android on Virtualbox but Genymotion has just release a emulator running on virtualbox which works without having to tweak anything.

http://www.genymotion.com/

You should take a look at that!

Comment: thanks Fergers i am gonna try that... bluestack is also there.. but i feel it is slowing down my machine...

Comment: Your welcome; Hope it will be just what you need! Inform me later if its working out for you ;)

Comment: Tried, not fully but it is not that i was wanting... i am not sure but it is useful for android developers